# htaccess rewrite part of filename to url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't figure out how to rewrite this:

```
/part-filename.php
```

to

```
/part/filename.php
```

/part/ is not an existing directory.

I know it should be quite easy, but can't find how to search for 'part' in the filename and translate that to a sub level in the url.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^part/(.*)$ /part-$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```